# How do I query Tcl about its version?

Tags: version, tcl, introspection

There must be an easy way to do this, but I can't find it.

What command can I run within Tcl to get it to introspect and report the version of itself that is running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
info patchlevel
```

which is the value of tcl_patchlevel

see [tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl28.html)

Answer (score 3):

in addition to other options, you can use:

```
puts $tcl_version
```

This has the advantage of working for comically old versions of tcl.

Comment: This only gives you the major version (8.5) but not the full version (8.5.7)

Answer (score 2):

You only need to

```
puts $tcl_patchLevel
```